# Remover vírgula do map

Tags: javascript, map

Boa tarde.

Estou tentando criar alguns elementos dinâmicamente vindos de uma API, só que estou rodando o map pra isso, o problema é que junto dele, aparecem virgulas no meio das li's que não imagino de onde são. Como posso contornar isso?

Vou simular o response da API abaixo:

```js
function personalInstaThumb() {
 const personalInstaThumb = document.querySelector('#personalInstaThumb')
 const response = [
        {
   images: {
    url: 'https://www.blogsenacsp.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/GettyImages-932559358.jpg'
   }
  },
        {
   images: {
    url: 'https://www.blogsenacsp.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/GettyImages-932559358.jpg'
   }
  },
        {
   images: {
    url: 'https://www.blogsenacsp.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/GettyImages-932559358.jpg'
   }
  }
 ]
 personalInstaThumb.innerHTML = `<ul>${response.map((img, indice) => `<li class="insta_thumb_item_${indice}"><img src=${img.images.url} width="150" height="150" /></li>`)}</ul>`
}
personalInstaThumb()
```

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="personalInstaThumb"></div>
```

Podem ver que depois de cada li, aparece uma vírgula. Por que e como posso "consertar" isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lucas, utilize `.join('')` para unir o resultado do seu `map`, o parâmetro fornecido para o `join` é o separador.

```js
personalInstaThumb.innerHTML = `<ul>${response.map((img, indice) => `<li class="insta_thumb_item_${indice}"><img src=${img.images.url} width="150" height="150" /></li>`).join('')}</ul>`
```

Comment: Que massa cara, tinha me esquecido do join. Mas você sabe me dizer de onde vem a vírgula?

Comment: @LucasdeCarvalho `map` [retorna um array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Return_value), e quando um array é transformado em string, os elementos são mostrados assim, com uma vírgula separando-os: https://jsfiddle.net/4abkpjus/